# Helping friend with project, how to tell him I'm not comfortable using my info for registering something?

Tags: friends, coworkers, trust

My friend wants to make a website and I would like to help him do this.

He asked me what free hosting to use and I suggested one. Part of the registration process is to upload photo ID.

My friend said he filled out the form but was never given an account, no password was ever created. He's now asking me to try with my ID. I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Since it is his website I feel it's better if the hosting is registered to him. I'm a bit concerned about liability and the privacy of my ID. Of course I trusted the host enough to suggest it to my friend, but I've never used it personally. However, I did some research and it has good reviews and fits what we need.

**How could I tell my friend I'm not really comfortable using my information and ID to register with the host?**

Comment: Have you considered that the service is "good enough" if you don't feel good sharing ID with them? You can always change your mind and say "you know what? let's chose one that is not so much hussle".

Comment: What's wrong with just telling that to your friend? What are you afraid will be your friend reaction if you just tell him that?

Comment: @Ælis usually I wouldn't recommend a friend do something I'm not comfortable doing

Comment: Trying your ID is not a solution, he should try again or contact the hoster for help. Reviews and trust towards the hoster is not your problem in this case. Your problem is that you are taking responsibility for web content not authored by you.